# Amplitude amplification on each register in a product state

Tags: circuit-construction, grovers-algorithm, amplitude-amplification

let oracle $U_\psi$ prepare a state $\psi$ with success probability $p$. For simplicity assume that $U$ requires a single ancillary qubit and $\psi$ is itself a single-qubit state:
$$
U_\psi |0\rangle|0\rangle = \sqrt{p}|0\rangle|\psi\rangle + \sqrt{1-p}|\bot\rangle \ .
$$

Now I want to prepare a product state $|\psi\rangle|\psi\rangle|\psi\rangle\ldots$ ($m$ times). The most naive implementation requires $m$ ancillas, each of which has to be measured in the $|0\rangle$ state, which results in total success probability $p^m$ (exponentially small in $m$!). I could also reuse the same ancilla for all the oracles but I'm not sure if this changes anything.

This estimate seems very strange to me — I would naturally expect that there should exist an efficient way to prepare $|\psi\rangle|\psi\rangle|\psi\rangle\ldots$ Am I missing something obvious?

**UPDATE**

Note that applying amplitude amplification to each register does not resolve the issue since it can only increase the success probability polynomially. Amplitude amplification would lead to success probability exponentially close to 1 in the number of qubits per each $|\psi\rangle$ register, but I want to keep this number fixed and potentially small. I asked a related question [here](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/34285/grover-amplitude-amplification-with-exponentially-high-success-probability).

Comment: if you know $\psi$, and the circuit is therefore allowed to depend on it (which isn't that demanding given $U_\psi$ here already does), you can simply clone it. Otherwise, for similar reasons, you'd need a circuit to clone $|\psi\rangle$ (for any $\psi$, with the circuit not depending on $\psi$), which cannot be done deterministically

Comment: What do you mean by simply "clone it"? Apply to each qubit register? Preparation of $|\psi\rangle$ is probabilistic and requires the measurement of the ancillary qubit in the $|0\rangle$ state, which happens with probability $p$ for a single qubit and $1-(1-p)^m$ for $m$ parallel circuits. Therefore, such an approach has success probability exponentially vanishing in $m$.

Comment: yes. If for example the state was $|0\rangle$ or $|1\rangle$, you'd use a series of CNOTs to map $|i\rangle$ to $|i\rangle^{\otimes n}$. Of course, you'd get $|i\rangle^{\otimes n}$ only conditionally to the first ancillary qubit used by $U_\psi$ being  $|0\rangle$, but still the overall probability would remain $p$ regardless of the final number of copies you get. Though I'm not sure I understand the context here. If you're allowed to use a circuit that depends on $|\psi\rangle$, you'd also probably be able to generate $|\psi\rangle$ deterministically in the first place

Comment: If $U_\psi$ implements a non-unitary transformation of the state register (upon measurement), there is no deterministic way way to implement it, this is the essential idea of block encoding, see chapter 6 in https://arxiv.org/abs/2201.08309

Comment: of course, if it's non-unitary then you cannot implement it deterministically, almost by definition. But you certainly don't need a non-unitary transformation to prepare a state. Again, you might have a specific context in mind, which might help make sense of what exactly you're asking about

Comment: I asked a related question [here](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/34285/grover-amplitude-amplification-with-exponentially-high-success-probability).